# How do I Instantiate a line renderer and give it positions for its points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I apologize for the block of code below but I am not sure where the issue is. I am trying to get a laser to appear off screen and attempt to hit the player. I have no idea why this code does nothing. It is most likey just a stupid mistake I have made.

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Lasers : MonoBehaviour
{

    private LineRenderer lr;
    public bool Above = true;
    public bool Below = false;
    public bool Left = false;
    public bool Right = false;
    public Transform LaserStartPoint;
    public Transform LaserEndPoint;
    public Transform Player;
    public float LaserWidth = 0.75f;
    public float LaserLength = 19f;
    public float LaserDuration = 0.5f;
    public float LaserFadeDuration = 0.5f;
    public GameObject Laser;
    
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            ShootLaser();
        }
    }

    void ShootLaser()
    {   

        if(Above)
        {
            LaserStartPoint.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10,10), 6, -1);
        }

        if(Below)
        {
            LaserStartPoint.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10,10), -6, -1);
        }

        if(Left)
        {
            LaserStartPoint.position = new Vector3(-10, Random.Range(-6,6), -1);
        }

        if(Right)
        {
            LaserStartPoint.position = new Vector3(10, Random.Range(-6,6), -1);
        }
        Instantiate(Laser, LaserStartPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);

        lr = Laser.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.startWidth = LaserWidth;
        lr.endWidth = LaserWidth;
        lr.positionCount = 2;  

        Vector3 dir = Player.position - LaserStartPoint.position;

        LaserEndPoint.position = LaserStartPoint.position + dir.normalized * LaserLength;


        lr.SetPosition(0, LaserStartPoint.position);
        lr.SetPosition(1, LaserEndPoint.position);

        Invoke("FadeLaser", LaserDuration);

    }

    void FadeLaser()
    {
        lr.startColor = Color.Lerp(lr.startColor, Color.clear, LaserFadeDuration);
        lr.endColor = Color.Lerp(lr.endColor, Color.clear, LaserFadeDuration);
        Laser.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

`

I have looked in the Hierarchy and nothing is spawning. None of the values are changing on the Script. I have the script attached to the main camera and it spawns in my LaserLineRenderer prefab.

Comment: You're not assigning a reference to your newly instantiated "laser" GameObject, and within the `FadeLaser()` method, you're disabling the prefab instead of the newly created object - is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to modify the line renderer component of the prefab. You need to grab the reference of the instantiated object when it is spawned in.

```csharp
private GameObject instantiatedLazer;

/*In ShootLaser function*/
instantiatedLazer = Instantiate(Laser, LaserStartPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
lr = instantiatedLazer.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

/*In FadeLaser function*/
instantiatedLazer.SetActive(false);
```